# mysql UPDATE variable

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys i have code like this

```
include('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['save']) && $_POST['save'] == '') {

    if(isset($_POST['misamarti'])){ $misamarti = $_POST['misamarti']; }
    if(isset($_POST['teleponi'])) { $teleponi = $_POST['teleponi']; }
    if(isset($_POST['posta'])) { $posta = $_POST['posta']; }
    if(isset($_POST['paqsi'])) { $paqsi = $_POST['paqsi'];}


    $query = "UPDATE contact SET  `misamarti` =  ".$misamarti.", `teleponi` =  ".$teleponi.", `posta` =  ".$posta.", `paqsi` =  ".$paqsi." WHERE  `contact`.`id` =1;";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

}

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="about" value="template1" />
<input type="text" value="" name"misamarti" />
<input type="text" value="" name"teleponi" />
<input type="text" value="" name"posta" />
<input type="text" value="" name"paqsi" />
<input type="submit" value="" name="save" />
```

and result is

> Notice: Undefined variable: misamarti in C:\xampp\htdocs\Template\admin_panel\contact.php on line 18
>   Notice: Undefined variable: teleponi in C:\xampp\htdocs\Template\admin_panel\contact.php on line 18
>   Notice: Undefined variable: posta in C:\xampp\htdocs\Template\admin_panel\contact.php on line 18
>   Notice: Undefined variable: paqsi in C:\xampp\htdocs\Template\admin_panel\contact.php on line 18

if anyone know why is this error pls comment.

Comment: The error messages say it all, really. You don't seem to be ever defining $misamarti. You also should sanitize your inputs, this is just asking for SQL Injection.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

You're using the variables even if they weren't submitted with the form, and update the fields in the db with those undefined varaibles, so you'll be destroying any data that was in the DB previously.

If nothing else, you need to at least set a default value for the fields, e.g:

```
 $misamarti = isset($_POST['misamarti']) ? $_POST['misamarti'] : '';
                                                                 ^^--default empty string
```

And then realize that you are WIDE OPEN to an [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com). You are BEGGING to get your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your HTML code, you have the names bad written, they have to be written this way: `name="misamarti"`. You forgot the equal (`=`) between `name` and the name. If you see the rest of attributes, like `text` and `value`, you see that theres an equal, that's the correct way of setting attributes.

Comment: Is realed, the error messages appears because the HTML code is bad formatted. I could say that he must check if the post data is set before getting all variables or something, but I've just asked the main question `if anyone know why is this error pls comment.`