# INPUT error PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {

    if (isset($_POST['a']) and $_POST["a"]!=='')
    {
     $misamarti = $_POST["a"];
     echo $misamarti;  
    }
  } 
?>

<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name"a" value="<?php echo $misamarti; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

After this I get

****Notice**:  Undefined variable: misamarti in
**C:\xampp\htdocs\template\admin_panel\1.php** on line **21****

This is inside of an input field.

Comment: Your variable does not exist if the form was not submitted. Try this `$misamarti?$misamarti:""`

Comment: Declare `$misamarti = "";` above the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` line of code. You won't have that variable declared if a `$_POST` request hasn't been made therefore it errors out.

Comment: Always use variables with meaningful variable names (and it's better to name them in English).

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql UPDATE variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925014/mysql-update-variable)

Comment: This is the third time you've asked this question.

Answer (score 2):

Because variable `$misamarti` will remain *undefined* till your form get submit.
So always have practice to *define/initialize* your variables.

```
$misamarti = ''
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
     if(isset($_POST['a']) and $_POST["a"]!==''){
        $misamarti = $_POST["a"];    
        echo $misamarti;  
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be `name="a"` in the `<input type=text`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you forgot an = at the input name.

And second, you should put the $misamarti in double quotes for it to work.

So the input should look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="<?php echo "$misamarti" ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`$misamarti` is only being defined when the `if()` condition is successful.

When the `if()` condition fails, the variable isn't defined. So then when you use it further down the code, it will throw the error you've reported.

You can fix this by defining a default value for the variable at the top of your code:

```
<?php
$misamarti = '';    //add this line at the top of the program.
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     //.... etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the keyword `and`, use `&&`
Also, define misamarti at the top, like this

```
<?php
$misamarti;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['a']) && $_POST["a"]!==''){
        $misamarti = $_POST["a"];
        echo $misamarti;  
    }
}
?>
```

With your HTML, a is undefined, since the Name is undefined

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="<?php echo $misamarti; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP expert, but I'd suspect that the scope of `$misamarti` is only inside of the `if` block, and so when you try to `echo` it later in the page it doesn't exist.  (At least that's how it works in other, more statically typed languages.)  If that's the case, define the variable outside of the `if` block first, setting it to some default value.  Something like this:

```
$misamarti = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['a']) and $_POST["a"]!=='') {
        $misamarti = $_POST["a"];
        echo $misamarti;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code may be help you..

```
  <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit']))
      {

        if (isset($_POST['a']) and $_POST["a"]!=='')
        {
         $misamarti = $_POST["a"];
         echo $misamarti;  
        }
      } 
  ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="a"  />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

and also try this code

```
    <?php
        $misamarti='';
      if (isset($_POST['submit']))
      {

        if (isset($_POST['a']) and $_POST["a"]!=='')
        {
         $misamarti = $_POST["a"];
         echo $misamarti;  
        }
      } 
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="a" value="<?php echo $misamarti ?>" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="text" name"a" value="<?php echo $misamarti; ?>" />
```

with

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="<?php echo $misamarti; ?>" />
```